# Handling errors in Azure Pipeline from csv file in blog to Azure Sql

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am making a pipeline in data factory that takes a csv file in blog and loads it into Azure SQL.
Some lines in the csv file will have a delimiter missing/extra. So for that particular row the number of rows in the csv file and in the Azure SQL table will not correspond.
I would like the process to continue working and store the faulty rows in an error table and let the process finishing the work.
Please help.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being discussed at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bd77151f-09e9-4ce6-9b7c-583fa5f6b583/store-non-corresponding-rows-rather-than-throwing-errors?forum=AzureDataFactory . Do refer there.

Comment: Sorry Harish the link points to a non answer. Can you point me to an example? or something that shows how to do it?